# Array to Hex Representation

Tags: c++, binary, hex

I am writing a program that needs to take an array of size n and convert that into it's hex value as follows:

`int a[] = { 0, 1, 1, 0 };`

I would like to take each value of the array to represent it as  binary and convert it to a hex value. In this case:

`0x6000000000000000; // 0110...0`

it also has to be packed to the right with 0's to be 64 bits (i am on a 64 bit machine).

Or i could also take the array elements, convert to decimal and convert to hexadecimal it that's easier... What you be the best way of doing this in C++?

(this is not homework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following assumes that your `a[]` will only ever use 0 and 1 to represent bits. You'll also need to specify the array length, `sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)` can be used in this case, but not for heap allocated arrays. Also, `result` will need to be a 64bit integer type.

```
for (int c=0; c<array_len; c++)
  result |= a[c] << (63-c);
```

If you want to see what it looks like in hex, you can use `(s)printf( "%I64x", result )`

Comment: need to subtract from 63… shift by 64 is implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I had to make the result type unsigned long long and cast the a[c] to unsigned long long also. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`std::bitset<64>::to_ulong()` might be your friend. The order will probably be backwards (it is unspecified, but typically index 3 will be fetched by right-shifting the word by 3 and masking with 1), but you can remedy that by subtracting the desired index from 63.

```
#include <bitset>

std::bitset<64> bits;

for ( int index = 0; index < sizeof a/sizeof *a, ++ index ) {
    bits[ 63 - index ] = a[ index ];
}

std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(64) << std::setfill('0')
          << bits.to_ulong() << std::endl;
```

Comment: I think he's trying to generate an `unsigned long` from an array of `int` . He doesn't have one to pass into `bitset` (I had already discarded this idea, but maybe I read the question wrong).

Comment: @Mark: Yeah, I edited the answer to reverse the sense like that. `bitset` works both ways.

Comment: +1 but I was wondering, does `std::copy` work with `bitset` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long long answer= 0;
for (int i= 0; i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); ++i)
{
    answer= (answer << 1) | a[i];
}

answer<<= (64 - sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
```

Assumptions: `a[]` is at most 64 entries, is defined at compile time, and only contains `1` or `0`. Being defined at compile time sidesteps issues of shifting left by 64, as you cannot declare an empty array.

Comment: It can have more than 64 entries, but i like this

Comment: @gprime, if it has more than 64 entries, what is the expected behavior?

Comment: there will never be more that 64...i would have to use a different datastructure if i wanted to. But i coded into my program to not attempt to perform the calculations if it's more than 64.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough answer:

```
int ConvertBitArrayToInt64(int a[])
{
    int answer = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<64; ++i)
    {
        if (isValidIndex(i))
        {
            answer = answer << 1 | a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            answer = answer << 1;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: It is a function that we do not have enough information from the original question to implement.  The implementation (or more likely, a suitable replacement) is left as an exercise to the implementor.

Answer (score 0):

byte hexValues[16];

for(int i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
{
    hexValues = a[i*4] * 8 + a[i*4-1] * 4 + [i*4-2] * 2 + a[i*4-3];
}

This will give you an array of bytes where each byte represents one of your hex values.

Note that each byte in hexValues will be a value from 0 to 16.